# Help me understand why I don't have to allocate this NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, dealloc, init

In firstViewController,

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[[SecondViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
// Pass data to secondViewController
[secondViewController setClass1:anObjectFromFirstViewController];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondViewController ...];

SecondViewController.m

Class1 *class1;
NSMutableArray *object2;
```

In viewDidLoad,
I think object2 points to the same object as class1 and therefore does not need to be allocated.

```
[self setObject2:[class1 someNSMutableArray]];
```

In init, I don't have to allocate object2 and the whole app still works. Is it because the object2 is pointing to the same item in memory as `[class1 someNSMutableArray]`.

If that is the case, then what happens if I do allocate object2. Will there be 2 copies? The app still works the same if I initialize it.

```
-(id)init { object2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; }
```

The confusing part is that if I initialize with autorelease, it will give me a dealloc error, the deallocating to a released object error

```
-(id)init { object2 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; }
```

Thanks mucho!!!

Comment: Offhand, Class1 and NSMutableArray are different types of objects, so this code looks dangerous.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the code snippets you put above. Does setClass1: retain the object?

Comment: @ThomasW. Sorry. The code is kinda confusing. But say Class1 have two properties: NSMutableArray array1, NSString string2. I am passing a class1 object from firstViewCtrl to secondViewCtrl. Then, in secondViewCtrl, I set a NSMutableArray in secondView to [class1Object array1]. Does that make sense? I may not be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea on the first part of the question is correct.

```
[self setObject2:[class1 someNSMutableArray]];
```

object2 is a variable which now contains the same address as [class1 someNSMutableArray]. So both point to the same NSMutableArray object.

This is different from:

```
object2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In this case you have **created** a new NSMutableArray object and put *that* address in the object2 instance variable. So that is now pointing to a different array than [class1 someNSMutableArray].

The key word there is "created". Think of alloc/init as creating a new object.

As for memory management:

```
object2 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I'm assuming you are (correctly) releasing object2 in the -dealloc for this class. So you have two releases (that release in dealloc plus this autorelease here) against only one retain (from the alloc/init), and therefore you are over-releasing the object.